# Плагин для определения CSS стилей для браузера

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста плагин для браузера Chrome или Firefox с помощью которого можно получить код CSS определенного элемента на сайте, т.к. есть CSS файл сжатый и искать в нем стили очень сложно, так как в нем более 30.000 строк.

Answer (score 0):

С сожалению, таких расширений нет. Но можно воспользоваться консолью разработчика. Для этого нажмите F12 или правой кнопкой на элементе странице => Просмотреть код. Справа будут находиться стили элемента. Сложно, не спорю, но вот такая тяжелая жизнь разработчика. Но вы зато сможете воспользоваться поиском с подсказкой filter с самом верху стилей в консоли. Насчет поиска стилей в Firefox не знаю, но в Google это точно есть.

[image]